# Проблема со скрытием блока

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть блок, который скрывается, если кликнуть вне него, но если я повторно нажму на кнопку, чтобы вызвать этот блок, то задний фон становится темным, но свойство display на block не меняется, его просто не видно. Как сделать, чтобы при повторном клике блок отображался?
Вот код скрытия блока:

```
function hideCover() {
      document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById('cover-div'));
    }
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
window.onclick = function(event) {

if (event.target == modal) {

modal.style.display = "none";
hideCover();
var container = document.getElementById('prompt-form-container');
container.style.display = 'none';  

}
```

Comment: вы указали метку jquery, хотя он тут не используется. Уточните, допустимо ли его использование в ответе.

Comment: @teran подойдет любое решение

Comment: есть у кого-то еще идеи?

Comment: @Midnight как видимо, нет.

Answer (score 0):

Вам не надо удалять блок, так как потом вы его не пересоздадите. Нужно использовать `hide()` и `show()`:

```js
unction hideCover() {
      if($('cover-div').is(":visible"))
      {
        $('cover-div').hide();
      }else{
        $('cover-div').show();
      }
}
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
window.onclick = function(event) {

if (event.target == modal) {

modal.style.display = "none";
hideCover();
var container = document.getElementById('prompt-form-container');
container.style.display = 'none';  

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: если использую ваш вариант функции, то при клике вне блока, фон позади остается затемнен и кликнуть никуда нельзя

Comment: там так то есть метод `toggle()`. но и в целом, начали писать с jquery, дак перепишите на него все.

Comment: @teran Лень......

Comment: если вам лень написать грамотный и качественный ответ, то лучше вообще не пишите.

Answer (score 0):

Удалять блок ни к  чему. Можно менять класс при нажатии, например: делать проверку класса, удалять его, если true, и менять на другой, и аналогично с обратным классом, можно оформить в jquery функции с if и методом toggle() или же простой проверкой с помощью локальной переменной

Comment: А вы не могли бы показать на примере кода?